# Django user.is_staff not working

Tags: django

i am in trouble with my django projet.

I would like to do that only staff user can see a link (href) in a template.

The template in which is the code bellow is the template base.html that I take in my other templates.

here is the header of base.html

```
<header class="header">
<img src="{% static 'img/headerWAI.jpg' %}" alt="HeaderWai jpg" class="headerimg" />
<h1 class="headerText">Waste Annotation Image</h1>
<p class="usermenu">
  {% block loginuser %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      Hello {{ user.username }}!
      <p><a class="loginlink" href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
      {% if user.is_staff %}
        <a href="{% url 'newimage' %}">manage image</a></p>
      {% endif %}
      {% else %}
      <p>You are not logged in : <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a></p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
</p>
```

user.if_authenticatted work correctly but 3 lines bellow, user.is_staff not work.

Out of 5 test users, only 2 have the boolean at True as staff. But when I am connect with a non-staff user, he has the link. I don't understand why?

Maybe i have forgot an import or something in the settings.py

my settings.py here : https://github.com/HE-Arc/WasteAnnotationImage/blob/master/wasteannotationimage/wasteannotationimage/settings.py

Any suggestion ?

PS: i am a beginner in django

Comment: does `{{ user.username }}` work for you? I just think it perhaps using `{{ request.user }}` to use current user. If you using `{{ user }}`, maybe having a conflict with another _context_ which following `{{ user }}` also. So Django replaced with your context.

Comment: `{{ user.username }} ` work

Comment: Your template looks ok and you have the auth context processor enabled in your settings, so `{% if user.is_staff %}` should work fine. Perhaps you are not logged in with the user you think you are, or perhaps you have set `is_staff` to `True` for that user by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

This is the right way

```
    {% if User.is_authenticated and User.is_staff == True %}
```

Comment: `{% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_staff  %}` with small "u"

Comment: No need for `== True` here. And the `user` object "magically" available from within templates is not uppercased.